# WPF app using Xamarin.Forms with .Net Core

Tags: wpf, .net-core, xamarin.forms

I am just starting a simple project, and would like to use Xamarin.Forms.  I need to support Windows 10 (could use UWP), but I believe also Windows 7 (WPF).  And, ideally iOS as well (and, maybe Mac & Android).  Plus, I'm quite familiar with Xamarin.Forms.

I created a "cross-platform" project (iOS, Android, UWP), and tried adding WPF following this info, but allowing it to be .Net Core instead of .Net Framework:
[WPF platform setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/wpf)

But, once I added Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF nuget, I got build warnings:

```
 warning NU1701: Package 'OpenTK 3.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 <tec>, instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I'm not exactly sure where to go here.   Should I drop back to the .Net Framework?  Is there an alternative to OpenTK 3.0 that uses .net core (there is, but I'm not sure how to make it work).

I just noticed that the verison of XF & ...Platform.WPF I'm using (4.7.0.1179) dropped TODAY.  Was that a good choice?

Comment: Notice that's just a warning. In many cases you can simply ignore that as WPF on .NET Core is mostly compatible to its .NET Framework counterpart. You only need to act when something breaks afterward.